# Make Capsule() move when swiping between tabs - matchedGeometryEffect

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm implementing a swiping tab view using SwiftUI's `PageTabViewStyle()` tabView style, similar to, say, Reddit mobile. On the top are all the tab names which turn blue, and right under a small `Capsule()` which moves to the selected tab. I'm having difficulty making the capsule move using `matchedGeometryEffect()` when the user has gone to a new tab, however.

```
// The parent view
@State private var selectedTab: Category = .all
// [...]
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    HistoryNavigationBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
            HistoryList(category: category)
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
}
```

With the important parts of `HistoryNavigationBar` being:

```
@Namespace private var animation
// [...]
ForEach(History.Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
        Button(action: { selectedTab = category }) {
            Text(category.rawValue.capitalized)
                .foregroundColor(selectedTab == category ? .blue : .gray)
        }
        Capsule()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 2)
            .foregroundColor(selectedTab == category ? .blue : .clear)
    }
}
```

How should I implement `matchedGeometryEffect()` to get the desired effect of the capsule moving every time the tab is changed? I tried all sorts of combinations with `matchedGeometryEffect()` (putting it after the capsule, putting the capsule in an if-statement, etc.), but to no success – whenever I swipe between tabs, or click on one of the tab names, the capsule just jumps to that tab.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the .matchedGeometryEffect on the capsule, but only draw the Capsule when the tab is selected (using an if-statement). You also need to add animation to the Capsule. Here is an example:

```
struct MGE: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab: String = "one"
    @Namespace private var namespace

    enum Category: String, CaseIterable {
        case one, two, three
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            ForEach(Category.allCases, id: \.self) { category in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    Button(action: { selectedTab = category.rawValue }) {
                        Text(category.rawValue.capitalized)
                            .foregroundColor(selectedTab == category.rawValue ? .blue : .gray)
                    }
                    if selectedTab == category.rawValue {
                        Capsule()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 2)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "capsule", in: namespace)
                            .animation(.spring())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I added a `hidden()` capsule of the same frame in the `else` block after the if statement, so that the text doesn't jump up and down. However, I've encountered another problem – if I jump quickly between the tabs, or tap quickly on different tab buttons to switch tabs, either one of two things happen, seemingly randomly: either the capsule's movements become sporadic, going to the wrong tab name or jumping between tab name, or the app just crashes. I'm guessing it's something to do with `matchedGeometryEffect()` and it blocking the main thread. What would you advise?

Comment: Happy to help. FYI, in my code ^^ I made the HStack have alignment of .top, to avoid the text jumping down. ... I can't replicate the app crash on my preview, so I'm not really sure what's causing it. One thing you could try is to set the isSource on the matchedGeometryEffect.